# ORACLE Join V$SQLAREA V$SESSION

Tags: oracle, join

which column i need to use to join V$session and V$sqlarea?

My main aim is to find top 5 queries with most disk_reads and generate a report containing relevant information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL does the join:

```
select s.sid, s.serial#, a.sql_text
from v$session s
join v$sqlarea a on a.hash_value = s.sql_hash_value;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try below one, I think it satisfy your requirement.
Find top 5 queries with most disk_reads.

```
SELECT SESION.SID,
       SESION.USERNAME,
       OPTIMIZER_MODE,
       HASH_VALUE,
       ADDRESS,
       CPU_TIME,
       ELAPSED_TIME,
       DISK_READS,
       DIRECT_WRITES,
       SQL_TEXT
  FROM V$SQLAREA SQLAREA, V$SESSION SESION
 WHERE SESION.SQL_HASH_VALUE = SQLAREA.HASH_VALUE
   AND SESION.SQL_ADDRESS    = SQLAREA.ADDRESS
   AND SESION.USERNAME IS NOT NULL
   AND ROWNUM < 6 
   ORDER BY DISK_READS DESC,ELAPSED_TIME DESC;
```